# Search through PDF files with PHP

Tags: php, search, pdf

I'm trying to find a way to search inside PDF files. I came accross the PHP PDF class but I can't seem to find any function for reading/searching a filestream.

So, as naive as I am, i tried to simple get a stream using file_get_contents(), obviously it's an encrypted-like output ;)

So my question, is there any way to search through PDF files? I'm looking for script-only / free / open source solutions and not buying some expensive commercial libraray.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[XPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/about.html)?

There is a blog post [here](http://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php) that may be of help.

There seems to be some code [here](http://community.livejournal.com/php/295413.html) that could help - a simple class that reads a PDF into plaintext. Unsure if it supports decryption.

There are also a number of resources in PHP documentation that may help you. [Click.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php)

[FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) and [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/) may also help. Probably your best bet after some research.**

Comment: Thanks I will check that out tomorrow! +1

Comment: I've gone through all your links and found out that the the mentioned class is not supporting encryption. So XPDF seems to be left over, since I'm working on a windowsmachine and having xampp installed I put all the files in the x:/xampp/apache/bin/xpdf/ directory. But I'm unable to execute the command mentioned in the blogpost you've send. Any suggestions on how to properly setup XPDF? (I don't know that much about webservers... did I even put the files in the right directory?)

Comment: It seems FPDF and FPDI don't allow to convert PDF to text. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959530/how-to-get-a-pdf-file-contents-with-php-using-fpdf-fpdi

Answer (score 2):

A PHP search engine called [Sphider](http://www.sphider.eu/) has the option of adding PDF search via XPDF. You can then customise the result templates to fit in with the rest of your site (if applicable).

Comment: This option still requires other libraries to be installed. 

"Download and install pdftotext and catdoc and set there location(path) in conf.php"

Comment: catdoc is only needed for MS-Office files, pdftotext is part of XPDF as I noted and is mentioned in the FAQ, "Indexing pdf and doc files".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, gave you +1 for your effort but its not something I'm looking for. Thanks.