# How I can use PHP to find a specific string or pattern in a PDF file

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

I am building an e-sign app with Laravel. It uploads a pdf file and read it to find a special string pattern like ##sign##. I do not know how to do this with PHP. It will be very helpful if anyone can help me in terms of Laravel.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at this: [Read pdf files with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004478/read-pdf-files-with-php)

Comment: Yeah, may be it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [one of the PDF libraries](http://www.pdfparser.org/) to read the data and use [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) functions to find and replace content with PHP. Or even simple [`str_reaplce`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php) could do the trick:

```
str_replace ('##sign##', 'Replace ##sign## with this', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

See this which have answer for your question

```
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882757/search-for-a-string-in-a-pdf-file-using-php][1]
```