# how can i read a hyperlink from a pdf using php ?

Tags: php, html, pdf

I have a pdf which contains some links.The link would not be like http://www.example.com/abcd.pdf.  but there are some text which is linked to some url. I just want to extract that url.

Comment: Are you able to get text from a PDF file yet? If not, have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882318/search-through-pdf-files-with-php. After that, you can search in the text for URL's with REGEX (for example).

Comment: i tried with other pdf reader. i am getting the text, but the link(url) associated with the text is not getting.

Comment: What are you trying to get the links? `preg_match_all` or something? Post your code..

Comment: @peter, 
I cannot post all codes here.The code is too long. I am using this code.
http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php

Comment: I mean the code after you extract the text from the PDF.

Comment: @peter, After reading the pdf by using that script, i can't see any link(url). That is the issue i am facing. If there is any link means we can get it by using 'preg_match_all'  as u said. 
If i open the pdf with notepad i can see the link. But when open using  'fopen('abcd.pdf', 'r')'  its returning binary(encrypted) values.After changing the extension to .txt its showing same binary format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to go for pdf read options seperately as i did initially. We can simply read pdf file by fopen() method or file_get_contents() method.

```
    $pdf_content = file_get_contents($actual_pdf_file, true);
    preg_match_all('/URI\(([^,]*?)\)\/S\/URI/', $pdf_content, $matches);
```

I wrote this preg_match_all functions according to my requirement. URI will be there for each link.

Now we will get the urls if any in $matches array. My case this url is a pdf download link. The code for downloading the pdf from the link is below...

```
foreach($matches[1] as $pdfurl)
    {       
    $CurlConnect = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_URL, $pdfurl);
    curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    @curl_setopt($CurlConnect, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    $Result = curl_exec($CurlConnect);
    $new_down_pdf='new_pdf_name.pdf';
    file_put_contents($new_down_pdf,$Result);
    }
```