# Searching text string and making changes in PDF file by PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I want to search a specific text string in the PDF. I have already extracted text from pdf and made small strings out of the text and stored in database. Also searched the specific text string, but now how to highlight it on the original PDF that the searched string is present at which position. Kindly help.

Comment: why can't you refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1882392/3164682

Comment: ThankYou Sarath for your prompt reply. This XPDF , FPDF and FDPI is good for making new PDF but not editing or searching in the original PDF.

Comment: Kindly suggest some other way to edit the original PDF