# Parse a PDF file using PHP at certain keywords and split it into multiple PDF files

Tags: php, parsing, pdf, symfony4

I'd like to be able to parse a PDF file using PHP and symfony 4 framework using certain keywords and split it into multiple PDF files at the keywords searched for.

I did some research and I found a lot of ways to parse PDF files using PHP but very few to parse and split the PDF file.

any web-sites I could go to? libraries I could use?

this is the code I used to extract the whole text from a pdf file. But my purpose is to extract specific paragraphes from the pdf, for example I want to extract the paragraph that starts from the word 'hello' to the word 'world'.

```
public function extract(): Response {
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
        $CV = $parser->parseFile('C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\papiers\CV\CVmolkahchaichi.pdf');

        // Retrieve all pages from the pdf file.
        $details = $CV->getDetails();
        $pages  = $CV->getPages();

        // Loop over each page to extract text.
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            echo $page->getText();
            foreach ($details as $property => $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {
                    $value = implode(', ', $value);
                }
                echo $property . ' => ' . $value . "<br/>";
            }
            return new Response();
}
```

Comment: Asking for libraries is discouraged on this site. That said, you have two parts, and you might need two tools. Part 1 is searching a PDF for a string, which is what I assume you mean by "parse a PDF file". This method should tell you what page numbers things are found on. Part 2 is extracting/deleting pages. (Duplicating a file and deleting content is the same as extracting.) See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1882392/231316) for some options. If you actually mean "parse a PDF", that something totally else.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.